WQL failing to get all records from DNS zone where records are more than 10k
int batchSize = 1000;
List<CimInstance> results = new List<CimInstance>();
int skip = 0;
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        var res = session.QueryInstances("root\\microsoftdns", $"WQL", $"SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord Where ContainerName = '{zoneName}'");
        results.AddRange(res);
        if (!res.Any())
        {
            break;
        }
        skip += batchSize;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}

Using code block like above.
Failing with exception after retrieving around 9k records
The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The WMI service or the WMI provider returned an unknown error: HRESULT 0x8004100a
Any suggestion on How to implement pagination using WQL or any efficient way?
Trying to get all records from the zone using pagination
